# How can i install npm module from github and build it?

Tags: node.js, github, npm, package, installation

There are a lot of github repositories with node modules.
Some of them published as NPM package and i can install it via `npm install <module>`.
And sometimes github contains only sources, and in `package.json` i can see `"prepublish": "npm run build"` and to NPM gets the bundles;
Also i have possibility to get module from github repository (`npm install <project>/<resository>`), but by default to `node_modules` gets sources and then i have to build it manually (for ex: `npm run build`). There is any option to get sources from Github and then build it immediately?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NPM will automatically run the lifecycle steps regardless of it being from Github, another SVC system or NPM. See the lifecycle scripts you can put your build processes in [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#description). Whatever project you want to install from Github will have already put their build process in the appropriate NPM scripts. Note that **NPM has changed how and when these scripts are executed on each of the last 4 versions of NPM**.

Run `npm i "jameswomack/string-is-empty#git-install-npm" -SE` on your project and see that it works.

[image]

See the test repo that installed from Github [here](https://github.com/jameswomack/test-git-npm-postinstall/tree/master)

See the test NPM package branch that outputs froma lifecycle script and was installed from Github [here](https://github.com/jameswomack/string-is-empty/tree/git-install-npm)

Comment: Yeah! that's what i need! Thanks!
And one more question: if i need some module for building (for ex: babel), how can i add this package only for building process?

Comment: @AlexanderKozlov if you need the build process to be run when the package is installed, it needs to be in the regular dependencies block. But if you can have the build run before the module is published, or before it's pushed to Github, you can put the build dependency in devDependencies, which aren't installed when people use your package.

Comment: Whats `-SE` argument? It's missing from [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install)

Comment: So only `postisntall` script runs? What if there is a `build` script and install only pulls sources and you need to build it?

Comment: @cdalxndr --save-exact

Comment: @cdalxndr & you'd need to add you build scripts to `postinstall`