# How to add dependency from another Github project?

Tags: node.js, github, npm, package

In my new project created using the command:

```
npm init
```

I want do add dependency from another GitHub project, so I used command:

```
npm install https://github.com/cichy380/prefixData.git --save-dev
```

but I got error:

> npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
>
> npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: git+https://github.com/cichy380/prefixData.git.
>
> npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

Can you explain me why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i install npm module from github and build it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185462/how-can-i-install-npm-module-from-github-and-build-it)

Comment: Answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46185462/how-can-i-install-npm-module-from-github-and-build-it presents https://github.com/jameswomack/string-is-empty project as exmaple, but with I do not have a problem to add this project (command: `npm install https://github.com/jameswomack/string-is-empty --save-dev` works fine). What is different beetwen jameswomack/string-is-empty and cichy380/prefixData project?

Answer (score 6):

I believe I can answer your question "Can you explain me why?"

Given the limited information in the question no one can for certain tell you the root cause of your error, but it COULD be one of these reasons:

1. The simplest problem could be there is no `package.json` in your repository;  **OR**
2. In your question you say that you executed the command:

   ```
   npm install https://github.com/cichy380/prefixData.git --save-dev
   ```

   This is not a valid [npm package git url format](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-packages-and-modules#npm-package-git-url-formats).  It's possible that if you used the protocol `git+https` you will not get that error, like so

   ```
   npm install git+https://github.com/cichy380/prefixData.git --save-dev
   ```

   I'm not sure if that's valid across all npm versions, but as you will see in the npm package docs link it does not allow for just `https` protocol; **OR**
3. Two reasons I can't say for certain **2** is your problem is **ONE**, not sure what version npm package you're using and what npm versions obey the docs I provided as a link and **TWO** your error you provided includes the `git+https` protocol so thats confusing:

   ```
   npm ERR! package.json Non-registry package missing package.json: 
   git+https://github.com/cichy380/prefixData.git.
   ```

Hopefully this helps someone!

Comment: "http..." instead of "git+http..." was my case. Thanks!

Comment: "git+https" worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I checked **package.json** file by [validator](http://package-json-validator.com/) and I found the error in this file. I [fixed](https://github.com/cichy380/prefixData/commit/ec64c6e81acf005d28105f8545f612855cec941a) it and now `npm install ...` command works fine! Thx

Comment: This helped me fix the `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that since May, 10th 2019, you also have the feature "[GitHub Package Registry (limited public beta for now)](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-05-10-github-package-registry-limited-public-beta/)"

> You can now publish public or private packages next to your source code.
>   GitHub Package Registry is fully integrated with GitHub and supports the following package management tools:
>
> - JavaScript (npm),
> - Java (Maven),
> - Ruby (RubyGems),
> - .NET (NuGet), and
> - Docker images.

See [more here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/about-github-package-registry):

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/package-registry/package-registry-page.png]

In your case: "[Configuring NPM for use with GitHub Package Registry](https://help.github.com/en/articles/configuring-npm-for-use-with-github-package-registry)"

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error while cloning the repo:

```
non-registry package missing package.json
```

Mistakenly I was cloning the repo using `npm install repo_link_here`

But that should be `git clone repo_link_here`

`npm install` is used to install the dependency of package.json